# FreeBSD: listing installed ports (without root access)

Tags: port, freebsd

I'd like to list which ports packages are installed on the wonderful web host [NearlyFreeSpeech.NET](http://www.nearlyfreespeech.net) (a FreeBSD system) and I tried

```
pkg_info
```

and

```
pkg_info -a
```

and I get no output, no errors.

The folder

```
/usr/ports
```

is a symlink to something but I cannot cd into it so I can't inspect the folders. Is there any easy way to list what ports packages are installed (for development purposes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NFS.net is really good about answering questions on their own forums. The admins of the hosts are very active on there. If you ask them they will tell you. If they don't tell you, it might be a breach of their [TACOS](https://www.nearlyfreespeech.net/about/terms) to get that info on your own.

Comment: Mmmmm....  Breached tacos....

Answer (score 1):

You're likely within a [chroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) jail for security reasons.

The best way is likely to contact the administrators and ask them for the information. I've been hosted on NFS in the past and have always found they have good support for this sort of thing.